# Unable to upload data to google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to upload an XML file to the google data store. The steps I have followed

-Use a sample guestbook application and upload it to google appengine using the correct app-id
-My app.yml looks like this:

```
application: app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: .*
  script: guestbook.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

-I want to upload an entire XML file to the datastore , so I enter:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://app-id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --kind=xml --filename=pathtoxml/xml
```

- The output produced is as follows:

> ```
> [INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader..
> [INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
> [INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
> [INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
> [INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
> [INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
> Error 404: --- begin server output ---
> <html><head>
> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
> <title>404 NOT_FOUND</title>
> </head>
> <body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
> <h1>Error: NOT_FOUND</h1>
> </body></html>
> --- end server output ---
> ```

-If I just type in myappid.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api it says page not found.

What am  I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The next step after `Batch Size: 10` is to open the db file.  So, I believe the 404 belongs to  the `pathtoxml/xml`.  `pathtoxml/xml` is not a valid file with extension.  Or, if you just made a typo above, try changing directories to the directory with the file (cd pathtoxml), and get rid of the relative path: `--filename=myfile.xml`.

Comment: I tried changing the path. That doesnt seem to be the problem. Is ther anything else I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the --filename specified now?

Comment: Also, I believe you have to specify the application: `appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://appname.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api  --application=s~appname  --filename=file.xml --config_file=bulkloader.yaml`

Comment: I just created a new project and did the exact same thing. It seems to throw this error now DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database but I think that is a differnt question and will post it under a new topic. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 1):

You receive the 404 error since the URL is not valid. In order to solve it, apart from changing the xml path using a correct file extension (answer from GAEfan), **remove the "_ah"** of the URL.

```
appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://app-id.appspot.com/remote_api --kind=xml --filename=myfile.xml
```